# Vector spaces and basis

Tags: vector-spaces

I came across this problem on vector space basis:
Verify that $2-x^2, x^3-x, 2-3x^2$ and $3-x^3$ form a basis for $P^4$ and express each of the polynomial $x^2$ as a linear combination of this basis.
I have tried solving the problem with my knowledge of vector space but still don't know how to go about it.
Any helpful solution to this?

Comment: Which vector space is $P^4$? Can you flesh out your question a bit? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Let's verify that the system of vectors $(2−x^2,x^3−x,2−3x^2, 3−x^3)$**(1)** is a basis for $P^4$. Write the canonical basis for $P^4$: $(1 ,x ,x^2 ,x^3)$**(2)** and decompose vectors of the system **(1)** by basis **(2)**:
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 2 & 3\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix} 
Now we'll proof linear independence of **(1)**:

$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 2 & 3\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 3\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix} 
\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 3\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -4 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Proofed,**(1)** is linear independent, $rankA=rank(1)=4$. But it is **maximal** linear independent for $P^4$( if we add any vector to **(1)**, it becomes linear dependent (definition of max. linear independent system)($dimP^4=rank(1)=4$)), so we can state that **(1)** is a basis for $P^4$.

2)Since **(1)** is a basis for $P^4$, we can decompose any vectors of the $P^4$ by **(1)**(definition of basis), including each of the polynomial $x^2$.

Comment: So, mark as answered

Comment: Please how have you done your reduction to the reduced echelon matrix, still finding it a bit difficult to understand

Comment: I've multiplied the last row by 3 and add it to the second and to the third row. Then I've divided the third row by -4 and add it to the first row. Then I've got a scalar matrix and it can be brought to the unit matrix by dividing its diagonal elements.

Comment: Still doesn't give me your matrix

Answer (score 0):

I think that $P^4$ is the space of all polynomials with degree $ \le 3$:

Since $ \dim P^4 =4$, you have to show: if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ and if

$$0=a(2-x^2)+b(x^3-x)+c(2-3x^2)+d(3-x^3)$$

then $a=b=c=d=0$.